# Selecting a dynamic checkbox in selenium using regex

Tags: regex, dynamic, selenium, checkbox

I am trying to select a checkbox whose ids are generated dynamically but couldn't solve it.
Tried following

```
Selenium.check("id=regexp:ctl00_cphMain_cbx_[a-zA-Z0-9_,]*")
Selenium.check("xpath=(//input[@type='checkbox'])[position()=1]")
```

Also this check box has only dynamic id, no name etc. any idea what I am doing wrong.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `selenium.check('xpath=//input[@type='checkbox' and starts-with(@id,'ctl00_cphMain_cbx_')])`

That should get what you are after