# how to select the check box using selenium?

Tags: selenium

How to select the checkbox which has a dynamically changing ID and XPath?

Comment: Attach sample of html and sample of your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting a dynamic checkbox in selenium using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280972/selecting-a-dynamic-checkbox-in-selenium-using-regex)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways:

1. You should look at a pattern like id or name somoething like
   CT_CHKBox_157, CT_CHK_158 etc.. For example, to click the first
   Checkbox having a pattern of Ids

You can use a dynamic xpath like driver.findelement(By.xpath(//input[starts-with(@id,'CT_CHK'][1]).click()

1. Identify the Unique Element which are close ancestors to the
   Checkbox in question and reach out to it through xpath or css path
   relatively or through indexing from within.

Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried XPath by position?  Ultimately the check boxes are like buttons or link that can be clicked so `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath by position")).click();`

Alternativey you might want to use JavaScript:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementsByName('ChkboxValue')[0].checked;");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium uses what is called locators to find and match the elements.There are 8 locators strategies included in Selenium:
Identifier
Id
Name
Link
DOM
XPath
CSS
UI-element

you can try using any other Locator in the list.

Comment: this answer is little deviated with the question. You can specifically say about handling with dynamically changing locators